# Need to run schedulers internally

Tags: http, ubuntu, tcp, cron, scheduler

I have a public website, which processes the data and run different schedulers for that data to process i.e. save data into db, send notifications to users

All these processes are running independently through the schedulers, and these processes are running concurrently

I am trying to run these schedulers using http, but using http the problem was up of available tcp ports into the system, because I have to process huge amount of data which will run millions of schedulers at a certain time, I have implemented the rate limiting also.

I have tried to run the schedulers using curl also, but it starts giving error

> too much open files

even I have increased the open file limit in my system to 1 million ,and curl occupies too much resources, so I am avoiding to go with curl

For more clarification on data, let's say I have 10,000 schedulers are running concurrently, and inside these schedulers, 10-20 schedulers(for each scheduler) are running in parallel for sending notifications, I am thinking to run these internal schedulers by another method rather than http or curl.

> Note:- I have to pass different data to each scheduler.

I am thinking to run these schedulers internally, can I do that?

Is there any better solution to run schedulers, by not using http or curl?

Comment: How is this question related to Go? Why HTTP?

Comment: @burakSerdar I am trying to run the code using golang.

Comment: What are these "schedulers"? Cronjobs? Why not write a single application to process these jobs triggered by a single "scheduler"? Your problem description is too high-level to make any useful recommendation.

Comment: Yes it's Cronjobs, you can check detailed summary of the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75007642/need-to-run-schedulers-using-net-http-concurrently